# How to hide a specific row from table using sql

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to show all data from "employee" table except the details of user which is logged in?

eg:

EMP_ID | EMP_Name

```
  1    |  Mike
  2    |  Peter
  3    |  Drake
  4    |  Oliver
  5    |  Andrew
```

Suppose, my current login user is "Peter" whose EMP_ID is 2, so I want to show table like this...

EMP_ID | EMP_Name

```
  1    |  Mike
  3    |  Drake
  4    |  Oliver
  5    |  Andrew
```

Basically I want to hide the details from table of current user. Please help me how to achieve it??

Comment: select only values that u want to show not `"SELECT * FROM"`

Comment: get the id of current logged in user and then `SELECT WHERE id != currentId` where currentId is id of current logged in user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you have to select everything you want and eliminate what you don't want:

```
SELECT *
FROM `employees`
WHERE `EMP_ID` != 2; -- eliminates Peter
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $query = "select EMP_ID, EMP_Name from EMPLOYEES where EMP_ID <> $emp_log";
```

I think that you know who is log by using a session var, so the var $emp_log must be get from the session var, ex.

```
 $emp_log = $_SESSION['emp'];
```